# Partial differential equation. 1D wave Initial Boundary Value Problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0  \text{ for }0 \leq x \leq 1$$

$$u(x,0) = f(x) $$

$$u_t(x,0) = 0$$

$$u_x(0,t) = 0$$

$$u_x(1,t) = 0$$

$$f(x) = 3x \text{ when } 0 \leq x \leq 1/3$$    and
$$ 3/2  (1-x) \text{ when } 1/3 \leq x \leq 1 $$

Find $u(x,t)$.

I found that $u(x,t) = f(x)$ when $x<t$ and $0$ when $x>t$.
I have doubts that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not trivial to solve this equation. The easiest way I could think of is to use a series-Ansatz:

$$
u(x,t)=a_0(t)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\cos(i\pi x)\cdot a_i(t)
$$

Here the cosine functions are chosen because they already fullfill the homogenous Nemann boundary conditions. Plugging it in the differential equation yields:
$$
a_0''(t)=0\\
a_i''(t)+(i\pi)^2a_i(t)=0
$$
Likewise we use the initial conditions
$$
\begin{cases}u(x,0)=a_0(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\cos(i\pi x)\cdot a_i(0)=f(x)\\
u_t(x,0)=a_0'(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\cos(i\pi x)\cdot a_i'(0)=0\end{cases}\\
\Rightarrow\\
\begin{cases}\int_0^1 \left[a_0(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\cos(i\pi x)\cdot a_i(0)\right]\cdot \cos(j\pi x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)\cdot \cos(j\pi x)dx\quad  \forall j=0,1,2,3\ldots\\
a_j'(0)=0\quad\forall j=0,1,2,3\ldots\end{cases}\\
\Rightarrow\\
\begin{cases}a_0(0)=\int_0^1f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{a_j(0)}{2}=\frac{3}{2}\frac{3\cos(\tfrac{j\pi}{3})-2+(-1)^{1+j}}{j^2\pi^2}\quad \forall j=1,2,3\ldots\\
a_j'(0)=0\quad\forall j\in\mathbb{N}\end{cases}\\
$$

Finally we can put it all together and end up with the series represenation of the solution:

$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty3\cdot\frac{3\cos(\tfrac{i\pi}{3})-2+(-1)^{1+i}}{i^2\pi^2}\cos(i\pi x)\cos(i\pi t)
$$

The below plot shows the behaviour of the function and you can see that it bounces back and forth from the walls (as expected) with a periodicity of $2$.

[image: Plot for $t<4&]